# KeyDown and KeyUp Multiple

Tags: c#, keydown

I am creating a piano in C Sharp and currently I have keyboard keys to play sounds. For example key A plays Note C. problem I am having is there I want to be pressing multiple keys at the same time and have the sound out. obviously I don't want to have to put all combinations in the keyDown class as I will have to make thousands of if statements. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows works with an only one message queue, so in each time only a key down message will be handled at a time unit. What you can do is to get all key down events in a short time interval (0.5 seconds for instace), save all key pressed in a list or a queue, then play all sounds according to the keys asynchronically (using threads). I have never have done this before, but I think should works. Hope helps...

**EDIT**

---

Ok, let see:
first the list where to save the keys

`List<Key> _keys = new List<Key>();`

Then start a timer for checking the keys pressed in a time interval:

```
        var t = new System.Timers.Timer(500);    //you may try using an smaller value
        t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
        t.Start();
```

Then the `t_Elapsed` method (Note that if you are in WPF an `DispatcherTimer` should be used, this timer is on `System.Timers`)

```
    void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_keys.Count > 0)
        {
             //Here get all keys and play the sound using threads
             _keys.Clear();
        }
    }
```

And then the on key down method:

```
void OnKeyDownMethod(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)  //not sure this is the name of the EventArgs class
 {
    _keys.Add(e.Key);    //need to check
 }
```

You may try this, hope be helpful.

Comment: woundering if you can show me an example code, i am really stuck on this part . kind regards